# Coq: How to prove "a=b -> nat_compare a b = Eq."?

Tags: coq, theorem-proving

In an attempt to get a grasp what Coq is about, I ended up in a situation where I essentially need to prove that `a=b -> nat_compare a b = Eq`.

I can get a handy start by doing:

```
Coq < Theorem foo: forall (a:nat) (b:nat), a=b->nat_compare a b=Eq.
1 subgoal

============================
forall a b : nat, a = b -> nat_compare a b = Eq

foo < intros. rewrite H. destruct b.
```

which gives me:

```
2 subgoals
a : nat
H : a = 0
============================
nat_compare 0 0 = Eq

subgoal 2 is:
nat_compare (S b) (S b) = Eq
```

The first is trivial:

```
foo < simpl. reflexivity.
```

But the next goal stumps me:

```
1 subgoal

a : nat
b : nat
H : a = S b
============================
nat_compare (S b) (S b) = Eq
```

I can do

```
foo < rewrite <- H.
```

which gives:

```
1 subgoal

a : nat
b : nat
H : a = S b
============================
nat_compare a a = Eq
```

(I can also arrive to this exact point by `simpl`, which seems to make more sense.)

Now, with pen an paper, I'd just claim that here is my proof by induction..

Am I approaching this at all in a correct way? Where can I best learn how to do this properly?

Comment: @jozefg It compares two nats. It is defined in coq standard library as "`Fixpoint nat_compare n m :=
  match n, m with
   | O, O => Eq
   | O, S _ => Lt
   | S _, O => Gt
   | S n', S m' => nat_compare n' m'
  end.`". Since I'm absolute beginner with Coq, this function might be totally wrong thing to use when comparing numbers, but..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to prove this with

```
Theorem triv : forall a b, a = b -> nat_compare a b = Eq.
  intros; subst; induction b; auto.
Qed.
```

The trick here is to leave the inductive hypothesis lying around. `destruct` is a weaker form of `induction` that doesn't give you an inductive hypothesis which you need for this proof.

Comment: Thanks! I did try `induction` earlier, but that failed when I used `rewrite H` in place of `subst`. If I additionally `clear` the hypothesis and reference to `a`, `induction` works with `rewrite`. Why do I need to clear the hypothesis first?